# How many times we can call spring boot REST api

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, rest

I have a requirement to read the message using the rest API  and send it to IBM MQ. There no logic in between. Just read the message and send it to MQ. The XML message size is 2 KB, Max.

I need to process 1M message per day, but REST API can process around 550 Messages per min which is not enough. I started 2 instances with a load balancer using the Netflix ribbon. but still, it can process only 650 messages per min.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object sendMessageToIBMQueue(@RequestBody String xml) throws IOException {
    if (appProperties.isSendToMQ()) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(appProperties.getBalance().getInputQueue(), xml);
    }

    return xml;
}
```

I used  `curl` to test this.

How many times we can call rest API in 1 min. I am not sure if it is a problem with code or rest API call.

Can someone help me to improve the process?

Comment: isSaveInputToFile = true in your tests or false?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli,  if isSendToMQ()=true &&  isSaveInputToFile()=false  then 500 messages per min. if isSendToMQ()=false &&  isSaveInputToFile()=true  then 550 messages per min.

Comment: The point is file saving and message sending is both IO and blocking. So will not get more throughput it one instance. On the other hand the question is how many connections IBM MQ is allowing at the same time

Comment: Can the Files.Write happen asynchronously?

Comment: You can consider writing file is disabled. I want to enable only sending messaging to mq. How to increase the throughput?

Comment: May be you can emit a "event" and listen to the same to send the message to IBM MQ, the reason why I am saying is that it will make your code asynchronous and shorten the lifespan of your api, as the api is now just emitting an event not pushing the message to another server/mq and due to quick response time your server will be able to handle more api request.

Comment: What hardware are you running this on?

Comment: @RajSaraogi, any given MQ should easily be able to handle 500 events per second, given sufficient hardware resources.

Comment: This is not a problem of the REST spec but a problem of how you implementing it. The default number of threads for Tomcat is 200 and you making this a blocking call. You may want to look at [Reactive Rest API using Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/) and [Spring Reactive Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html)

Comment: Try to process them in a batch by sending  more than one message, this will reduce http calls. Is any  compression enabled, no matter if the message is 2k. You could use a java profiler and see the bottlenecks  - could be issue with memory or threads a blocking.

Comment: @PriyakDey  I will check those options.

Comment: @Traycho I will check your suggestion too.

Comment: @sree1611 any solution you found out for this ?